# Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting

Tags: c#, api, iis

I wanted to put the migration of our web api in IIS and it send me this error message when I set the `stdoutLogEnabled` to `true` in the `web.config` file:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>      at TITSuiteWebapi.Program.Main(String[] args)

But when I wanted to browse in the api, I have this :
[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your application needs Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting in version 2.0 and either that dll isn't deployed to your server, or your applications dependencies need Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting with a different version

Comment: Thank you for your help.

In fact, my Microsoft.AspnNetCore's dependencies don't automatically update them when I update the package so Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting and other package where under version.